# Output Provides a strange value

Tags: c

This program Takes 5 votes , and sorts out for the candidate, and if the value isn't in 1-5 range , it throws in Spoilt ballot/count variable.

It gives a very strange output , and for count variable it gives me Null pointer assignment. 
No errors while compilation.

Please help me.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n[5];
    int a,b,c,d,e;
    int o[5]={1,2,3,4,5};
    int count;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        printf("Cast your Vote:");
        scanf("%d",&n[i]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(n[i]==o[1])
        {a+=1;}
        else if(n[i]==o[2])
        {b+=1;}
        else if(n[i]==o[3])
        {c+=1;}
        else if(n[i]==o[4])
        {d+=1;}
        else if(n[i]==o[5])
        {e+=1;}
        else
        {count+=1;}
    }
    printf("Vote for A canditae %d ",a);
    printf("vote for b %d  ",b);
    printf("Vote for C: %d",c);
    printf("Vote for D : %d",d);
    printf("Vote for E: %d",e);
    printf("Spoilt Ballots: %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look on your loop over the `o`-array. How many elements does it have and which is the highest valid index?

Comment: 5 elements and i guess 4 is highest.

Comment: @user3604972 right so o[5] isn't valid.

Comment: I tried removing O array , and putting numbers there directly. I can't seem to find what is wrong.

Comment: `o[5]` is undefined behavior. Also, it seems like you understand the concept of loops... so why not use one to check values in your `o` array?

Comment: Wait, I'll edit the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't initialized `a, b, c, d, e`. In your if-else ladder you're basically adding one to an undefined value. You should initialize

```
int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0;
```

and you'll see much more sane results. You also need to fix the out of bounds access on the `o` array as mentioned in the comments.